# How to handle await self.request.post()['users'] with multiple variables from HTML select tag for the same parameter in Aiohttp?

Tags: html, request, html-select, aiohttp

I want to receive users that a user has chosen to create a group chat. In an Aiohttp to get variable from HTML select tag, I use self.request.post()['variablename']:

```
@login_required
async def post(self):
  data = await self.request.post()
  chat_topic = data.get('chat_topic', '').lower()
  users = data['users']
  await Chat.create(topic=chat_topic, users=group_users)
```

This is my rooms.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="{{ app.router['create_chat'].url_for() }}">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Create new chat</h2>
        <label for="chat_topic" class="sr-only">chat topic</label>
        <input name="chat_topic" type="text" id="chat_topic" class="form-control" maxlength="32" placeholder="chat topic" required autofocus>

    <label for="users"> Choose users: </label>
    <select name="users" id="users" multiple="multiple">

        {% for user in users %}
            <option value="{{ user.id }}">
            {{ user.username }}
            </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">create chat</button>
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

Unfortunately, I receive only the last selected user as a string, not all of selected users. How can I get an array of selected users in aiohttp from an HTML select tag?

I know that in Django, I could do something like this:

```
users = request.POST.getlist('users')
```

I will appreciate any help!